# Refactor dropdown component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring, semantic-ui

I have to use multiple dropdowns from semantic-ui-react in my project. They need to have different props. It looks like this

```
 <div className="wrapper">
        <img className="icon" src={iconA} alt="iconA"></img>
        <h1>A</h1>
        <Dropdown
          className="dropdown"
          search
          selection
          options={optionsA}
          placeholder="A"
          defaultValue="A"
          onChange={handleAChange}
        />
 </div>
 <div className="wrapper">
        <img className="icon" src={iconB} alt="iconB"></img>
        <h1>B</h1>
        <Dropdown
          className="dropdown"
          search
          selection
          options={optionsB}
          placeholder="B"
          defaultValue="B"
          onChange={handleBChange}
        />
 </div>
```

I want to refactor this and create a single component for this by pasing different props. Please guide me on how this can be refactored in the best way possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create your custom dropDown component and extract props using object destructuring, you can give deafult values to props there itself, but better use PropTypes for that.

```
const CustomDropDown = (props) => {
  const { 
    className,
    search,
    selection,
    options,
    placeholder,
    defaultValue,
    onChange
  } = props;

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <img className="icon" src={iconA} alt="iconA"></img>
      <h1>A</h1>
      <Dropdown
        className={classname}
        search={search}
        selection={selection}
        options={optionsA}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now, call the component like this,

```
<CustomDropDown 
  className="dropdown"
  search
  selection
  options={optionsA}
  placeholder="A"
  defaultValue="A"
  onChange={handleAChange}
/>
```

Comment: That helps! I think you missed the the `img` and `h1` tags in the component. They need to have different props too!

Comment: yes, you can pass those too from <CustomDropDown  /> component, and consume it.

Comment: There is also a special case where let's say I would want another `p` tag within `div ClassName="wrapper"` but only for a specific dropdown. Would that be possible?

Comment: you can use flag for that, i mean pass a boolean flag as a prop and display `p` tag based on that

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
const DropDownWraper = ({
 header,
 options,
 onChange,
 iconProps,
 placeholde,
 defaultValue
 }) =>
    <div className="wrapper">
      <img
        className="icon"
        src={ iconProps.src }
        alt={ iconProps.alt } />
      <h1>{ header }</h1>
      <Dropdown
        search
        selection
        options={ options }
        className="dropdown"
        onChange={ onChange }
        placeholder={ placeholde } 
        defaultValue={ defaultValue } />
   </div>
```

Comment: The dropdown have different onChange functions

Comment: When you use the DropDownWraper component, you can pass handleAChange, handleBChange, etc. The same is true for everything else.